# jQuery dataTables and animated SVG when processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, datatables

I'm quite new to the jQuery dataTables. In fact, I have been working with it on a beginner level for less than a week.

In an application I'm working on for a client, one of the dataTable options is the language with an img tag for the Processing option. Like this:

```
"oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<img src='<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>/asset/img/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>",
            "sSearch":       "S&oslash;g:",
            "sLengthMenu":   "Vis _MENU_ linjer",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "F&oslash;rste",
                "sPrevious": "Forrige",
                "sNext":     "N&aelig;ste",
                "sLast":     "Sidste"
            }
},
```

As a part of the UX optimization for the application, I wanted to change the old gif loader with a more modern approach. I started to look into SMIL (animated SVGs) with a fallback for older browsers and then I entered a jungle of solutions!

I came across a guide: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-svg-fallbacks/ but I'm not sure if this works for SMIL?

So my questions is:
- What would be the best way to implement an animated SVG with a fallback for older browsers?
- And how to make it work in this "sProcessing"-option for the dataTable?

Notice, the application was made by another developer, hence I have not made this solution. I'm just optimizing the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SVG fallbacks or feature detection needed for them but you would need to use a JavaScript variable or function to return the appropriate value for `sProcessing`

Something like:

```
var processing_img;
if(svgFeatureDetecion){
   processing_img = 'your-svg-source';
} else {
  processing_img = "<img src='<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>/asset/img/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>";
}

var tableOpts={
   "oLanguage": {
      "sProcessing": processing_img,
      // ...
   }
};

$('#my-table').DataTable(tableOpts);
```

Comment: That's actually a great approach! In this way you wouldn't risk for the page to load both resources (the SVG and the fallback) at the same time. Worth looking into.